# How to log in to site after removing login form

Tags: users

After I logout. I couldn't login. I didn't assign the block for the user login. I tried out ,

1. ?q=user
2. $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
3. $form = drupal_get_form('user_login');

It displays:

> User account Error
>
> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

How to get the log in. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is to reset the default theme to Bartik or one of the other core themes to log in, then you can fix your mistake there.

**Using Drush:**

```
drush vset theme_default bartik
```

**Not using Drush:**

Look in your `variables` table and switch out whatever is currently in `theme_default` for `bartik` (ensure that the number following from `s:` matches the number of letters in the theme name, so Bartik would be 6, Garland would be 7)

```
UPDATE variable SET value='s:6:"bartik"' WHERE name = 'theme_default';
TRUNCATE cache;
```

(Modified from [Unusable theme - How To reset your theme](http://drupal.org/node/200774))

Comment: Please say how to use drush vset theme_default bartik

Comment: Tutorials on Drush and CLI are out of scope for this site.  If you don't know how to use Drush, then follow the second set of instructions :)